# A literature reference for Sobolev mappings $W^{m,p}(M,N)$ for M, N smooth Riemannian manifolds

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, compact-manifolds

Anyone know a respectable reliable reference for the definition of Sobolev mappings $W^{m,p}(M,N)$ for M, N smooth compact Riemannian manifolds. It suffices for m natural and $p\geq 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

1. [Intrinsic weak derivatives and Sobolev spaces between manifolds](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5858) by Alexandra Convent and Jean Van Schaftingen
2. [Gromov's compactness theorem for pseudo holomorphic curves](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1994-342-02/S0002-9947-1994-1176088-1/S0002-9947-1994-1176088-1.pdf) by Rugang Ye